# JavaScript как объединить результат с API в существующий массив

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Подскажите, как правильно сделать такую функцию. Использую javascript с фреймворком React

```html
        let fData;
        let lData  = [];

       
        for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i ++){
            fData = {
                ...data[i],
                credit: {
                  bank: axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/products/credits/" + data[i].credit.id)
                                          .then(function(result){
                                              return result.data.partner.name;
                                          })
                }
            }
            lData.push(fData);
        }

       console.log(lData);
```

Данный код возвращает то что ниже. Как получить Bank Name X

```html
credit:
bank: Promise
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: "Bank Name X"
```

Comment: `result.data.partner.name` это и есть `"Bank Name X"`?

Comment: да )  именно так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let fData;
let lData  = [];
let pData = [];

       
        for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i ++){
            pdata.push(axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/products/credits/" + data[i].credit.id))
            fData = {
                ...data[i],
                credit: {
                  bank: "blank"
                                          
                }
            }
           lData.push(fData);
        }

Promise.all(pData).then(function(result){
    for(var res in result){
        lData[res].credit.bank = result[res].data.partner.name);
    }
    console.log(lData)
})
```

`Promise.all()` позволяет по завершению всех запросов получить массив результатов. Это единственный способ, поскольку `axios` работает в асинхронном режиме.

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Теперь попробую разобраться. Спасибо еще раз. Премного благодарен